# Getting "Server temporarily unavailable. AUP#MXRT" while sending bulk emails (Deferred Emails)

Tags: linux, smtp, vps, exim, bulk-email

I have a VPS server with CPanel on my domain (say mydomain.com). I have a SuiteCRM installed on a subdomain (say sub.mydomain.com) and I am sending mass emails from it in a batch of 90 every hour.

While sending the emails from the CRM (Authenticated SMTP mode) the emails are getting deferred with the error:

`SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM:< myemail@mydomain.com> SIZE=562346: 451 <myemail@mydomain.com> server temporarily unavailable. AUP#MXRT`

The SPF, DKIM and DMARC everything is fine.

I am suspecting it could be a max rate warning/failure (MaXRaTe hence MXRT) from the remote/recepient mail server. It is failing/deferring emails for Gmail, Yahoo and other email providers not for any company-specific emails like someone@somecompany.com

There seems a limit on emails for Gmail and other vendors. I had gone through these where Gmail specifically pointing out the limits and do's and don'ts:

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22839?hl=en#zippy=%2Cyou-have-reached-a-limit-for-sending-mail

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126

In my case, I find myself well under the limit. So, why I am getting this error?

Second thought: It could be due to that I am sending 90 emails in one go. If I send emails one-by-one after a delay (say 3-5 seconds) then there won't be any problem. Enlighten me on this too.

I later realized that, even any one-to-one email I am sending via Thunderbird from my server (SMTP), even to a single recepients, is failing. I have checked check.spamhaus.org and intodns.com everything is alright there.

My Environment (Though this hardly matter in context of my problem but just in case):

BigRock's VPS Server with CPanel (Version)

Apache Version: 2.4.53

MySQL Version: 8.0.29

WHM Version: 102.0.18

CentOS Version: 7.9.2009 (Standard KVM)

*Note: I haven't mentioned my actual domain name just for the privacy and security since I feel putting everything here will pose risks.*

Comment: Is it possible most/all of these messages are being sent to email-to-SMS gateway services?  Specifically @mms.att.net and vzwpix.com and vtext.com and the matching tmobile one ?   It seems all of these cellco's now outsource their email to SMS gateway service and all to the same company.